# The first proof for Poincare lemma in history

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, math-history, differential-forms

How can I get a reference about the first proof of Poincare lemma in history? I already know some methods of proof, but I do want to know the original approach. Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555783/first-proof-of-poincare-lemma.