# Poincare: Change of form to a primitive 1-form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Given a 2-form w on $R^3$, such that dw=0; how does one find all 1-forms k such that dk=w?

Provided a homotopy H(t) one can pull back w and apply the Poincare operator on it. But what if one does not have a homotopy to start working with?

Comment: Where is this $2$-form defined on?

Comment: If you want to find **all**, then first find one (call it $\alpha$).Then if $k$ is a one form so that $dk = \omega$, then $dk = d\alpha \Rightarrow d(\alpha - k) = 0$. Then there is a function $f$ so that $df = \alpha - k \Rightarrow k = \alpha - df$. So the main point is to find one $\alpha$ first.

Comment: highly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555783/first-proof-of-poincar%C3%A9-lemma

Comment: What exactly is f here?

Comment: A function (so is also a $0$-form)

Comment: Look up [integration of differential forms over manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Integration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your form is defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$, then there is always the linear homotopy which contracts every point to the origin.

Comment: Replace each variable $x_i$, $1\leq i\leq 3$ with $tx_i$ to get another 2-form in 4 variables $x_i$ and $t$. Integrate the terms involving $dt$ with respect to $t$ to get the primitive 1-form.

Comment: Exactly what I meant. Note that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is contractible, and the linear homotopy is a natural one which witnesses the contraction to the origin.

Comment: Of course any other homotopy witnessing contraction to a single point will do. For instance $H(t, x, y, z)=(t^2x, t^{666}y, t^{167}z)$